# Invalid token '}' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

```
namespace WebPORTAL.Models
{
    public class Users
    {
        [Key]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "FIRST NAME")]

        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "LAST NAME")]

        public int Age { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "DATE OF BIRTH")]

        public string Address { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "ADDRESS")]

        public int MobileNumber { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "CELLPHONE NUMBER")]

        public string Email { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "EMAIL ADDRESS")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "PLEASE ENTER VALID EMAIL ADDRESS")]

        public string Username { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "USERNAME")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "PLEASE ENTER YOUR USERNAME")]

        public string Password { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "PASSWORD")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "PLEASE ENTER YOUR PASSWORD")]

    } 
}
```

I don't see what's wrong with the code.

Comment: I suppose your attributes (e.g. `DisplayName`) should be *before* the property, not after it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Attributes top of your property, not below of property,

you can try that:

```
    [Key]
    [Display(Name = "FIRST NAME")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "LAST NAME")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "DATE OF BIRTH")]
    public int Age { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "ADDRESS")]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "CELLPHONE NUMBER")]
    public int MobileNumber { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "EMAIL ADDRESS")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "PLEASE ENTER VALID EMAIL ADDRESS")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "USERNAME")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "PLEASE ENTER YOUR USERNAME")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "PASSWORD")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "PLEASE ENTER YOUR PASSWORD")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
```

Comment: Isn't this exactly the same as the answer offered by @PatrickHofman?

Answer (score 1):

You have put your attributes on some properties *after* the property. They should come directly *before* the property it concerns.

The 'problem' now is the last attribute which doesn't have an associated property. That is why it is failing.